# Delete a file called '.env'$'\r'

Tags: filenames, rm, delete

I have no idea what created this file - I guess a terrible shell script.

It is called `'.env'$'\r'`

I have tried various versions of `rm`, and the technique of opening the direcory with `vim ./`, selecting the file, and Shift-D to delete.
This didn't work, failing with a

```
**warning** (netrw) delete(/root/squawker/.env) failed!
NetrwMessage [RO]
"NetrwMessage"  --No lines in buffer--
```

How can I delete this pesky file?

This is on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I expect the cause is a shell script that somehow acquired DOS line endings - check your script files for trailing carriage returns.  Examining the content of the file might give you a clue as to where it came from.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

On recent-ish Linux systems (with GNU tools as in most desktop distributions), `ls` prints names with weird characters using the shell's quoting syntax. If that `'.env'$'\r'` is what `ls` gives, the name of the file is `.env<CR>`, where `<CR>` is the carriage-return character. You could get that if you had a shell script with Windows line-endings that ran e.g. `whatever > .env`.

The good thing here is that the output of `ls` there is directly usable as input to the shell. Well, to Bash, ksh, and zsh at least, not a standard POSIX sh, like Debian/Ubuntu's `/bin/sh`, Dash.

So try with just

```
rm -f '.env'$'\r'
```

Of course `rm -f .env?` should also work to remove anything named `.env` plus any one character.

Now, of course it's also possible that the filename is literally that, what with the single quotes and backslashes. But that's more difficult to achieve by accident. Even so, `rm -f *.env*` should work to delete anything with `.env` in the name.

Comment: `$'.env\r'` would be a clearer / more readable way to write it, with the whole thing inside C-escape-expanding quotes.  Oh, but that is how `ls --quoting-style=shell-escape .env*` prints it, unfortunately, if I `touch` that filename first.  This looks like a good use-case for `rm -i .env?` or `.env*` as another answer points out.

Comment: Note that it's a behaviour of the GNU implementation of `ls`, it has nothing to do with Linux.

Answer (score 23):

If using GNU `find`, then you can delete it by the inode.

```
ls -lid -- .env*
```

The number in the first column is the `inode`. Note what it is for the file that you actually want should others with the string `env` in the filename exist.

```
find . -inum <inode> -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Replace `<inode>` with the actual inode number. You can remove the `-exec` part so that you know that it is returning the file that you want before deleting it.

You can also use:

```
find . -inum <inode> -delete
```

I sometimes use the `-exec` bit out of habit but either one works.

Comment: `*env*` expansion would not include the OP's `.env<CR>` file which is a hiddent file though.

Answer (score 13):

Ask the shell to wildcard the tricky part of the name, and ask `rm` to remember it for you so you don't need to type it.

```
$ touch '.env'$'\r'
$ ls -l .env*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 paul paul 0 May 20 16:51 '.env'$'\r'
$ rm -i .env*
rm: remove regular empty file '.env'$'\r'? y
```

Comment: If you are on a GUI, you can cut'n'paste the output of `ls` into the `rm`

Answer (score 11):

A quick-and-dirty way to select pesky filenames is to use the autocompletion feature of the shell.

Type `rm` , then hit the TAB key until the file to remove is printed on screen.

Comment: Which shell, configured how?

Comment: zsh would rotate between the matching ones, but I don't think Bash can do that. So, `.env<tab>` would work in Bash if there's only that one filename starting like that. But if e.g. `.env` also exists, then the completion doesn't really help.

Comment: With BASH, if you press TAB twice in a row, it shows all the completions, but it doesn't escape them correctly (I tried with a newline in the filename)

Comment: @CSM, it does autofill correctly, though, if it's the only matching filename. But you can't copypaste from the listing.

Comment: For bash use `"'.en` and then TAB.  The file name should be completed correctly.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: Most likely the question title is misleading, and the OP copied the output of GNU `ls --quoting-style=shell-escape`.  This and other answers and comments are assuming that, not that the question title is literally true. (That's what I assumed, though, when seeing it in HNQ before clicking.  But much more likely to be `.env` with a stray carriage return).  I think your suggestion is for `'.env'$'\r'` as the literal filename, starting with a literal single-quote, and you're enclosing that in double-quotes for the shell.

Comment: @PeterCordes sounds right.  Thanks!